# Conan (C++) cross-compilation of package: Windows x86_64 (64 bit) to Windows x86 (32 bit) with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, devops, conan

I'm currently trying to create a Conan package (library) from source code for a legacy version of log4cplus to be compatible with 32 bit builds on Windows 64 bit. I have no success so far and unfortunately the Conan documentation is not helping me here, as well as any scarce existing cases on StackOverflow, etc.

## Files

My directory looks like this:

```
conan/
├── config/
│   └── profiles/
│       ├── windows32debug
│       └── windows64debug
├── remotes.json
├── settings.yml
└── packages/
    └── log4cplus/
        └── conanfile.py
```

remotes.json

```
{
   "remotes":[
      {
         "name":"conancenter",
         "url":"https://center.conan.io",
         "verify_ssl":true
      },
      {
         "name":"artifactory2",
         "url":"http://localhost:8046/artifactory/api/conan/conan-local",
         "verify_ssl":true
      }
   ]
}
```

windows32debug:

```
[settings]
os=Windows
arch=x86
build_type=Debug
compiler=gcc
compiler.cppstd=11
compiler.version=7.3
compiler.threads=posix
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
```

windows64debug

```
[settings]
os=Windows
arch=x86_64
build_type=Debug
compiler=gcc
compiler.cppstd=11
compiler.version=7.3
compiler.threads=posix
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
```

conanfile.py (log4cplus)

```
from conan import ConanFile
from conan.tools.cmake import CMakeToolchain, CMake, cmake_layout, CMakeDeps
from conan.tools.scm import Git

class log4cplusRecipe(ConanFile):
    name = "log4cplus"
    version = "1.1.3-rc3"

    # Optional metadata
    license = "Apache Public License 2.0 and two clause BSD license"
    author = "<Put your name here> <And your email here>"
    url = "https://github.com/log4cplus/log4cplus/releases/tag/REL_1_1_3-RC3"
    description = "log4cplus v1.1.3-rc3"
    topics = ("<Put some tag here>", "<here>", "<and here>")

    # Binary configuration
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    options = {"shared": [True, False], "fPIC": [True, False]}
    default_options = {"shared": False, "fPIC": True}

    # Sources are located in the same place as this recipe, copy them to the recipe
    exports_sources = "CMakeLists.txt", "src/*", "include/*"

    def source(self):
        git = Git(self)
        git.clone(url="https://github.com/log4cplus/log4cplus.git", target=".")
        git.checkout("REL_1_1_3-RC3")

    def config_options(self):
        if self.settings.os == "Windows":
            self.options.rm_safe("fPIC")

    def configure(self):
        if self.options.shared:
            self.options.rm_safe("fPIC")

    def layout(self):
        cmake_layout(self)

    def generate(self):
        deps = CMakeDeps(self)
        deps.generate()
        tc = CMakeToolchain(self)
        tc.generate()

    def build_requirements(self):
        self.tool_requires("cmake/3.27.5")
        if self.settings.arch == "x86_64":
            self.tool_requires("mingw-builds/12.2.0")
    
    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure()
        cmake.build()

    def package(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.install()

    def package_info(self):
        self.cpp_info.libs = ["log4cplus"]
```

### Configuration

I installed the configuration like this

```
conan config install conan\config
```

Then I create the package:

```
conan create conan\packages\log4cplus --profile:host=windows32debug --profile:build=windows64debug
```

To which I get the error:

```
Cmake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.
  ...
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
  ...
```

The package mingw-builds/12.2.0 should have the toolchain and all the necessary binaries, I don't want to have to specify a toolchain found in my machine. Any ideas?

Comment: You're only specifying a mingw-build/12.2.0 dependency for 64-bit builds.

Comment: In most cases you dont want the "build" profile to be Debug, why would you like to run cmake or gcc in Debug mode? For Debug builds, typically only the "host" profile needs to be Debug.

Comment: I'd say this needs a bit more information, like the full logs, etc. I'd recommend filing a ticket in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues instead, where more support-like conversation can happen. I suspect that ``mingw-builds/12.2.0`` is not being used if the architecture is 32 bits, so then mingw is not there and it fails, but it would be necessary to see the full logs.

Comment: John, you’re right. But I had tried it before: taking the ‘if self.settings.arch == "x86_64":’ away, then I get “Mingw 12.2.0 is only supported for the following architectures on Windows [‘x86_64’]”